# certificate and private key for push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate

I need cert.pem and key.pem for API(in my node js backend) but I just download .cert file from App IDs -> Edit -> Download. How can I get it, I can extract it from .cer file?

Comment: Why don't you read the push notification programming guide?

Comment: @Desdenova I read it, but some concepts is not understandable for linux user. I should run some mac specific applications, M.S.B helps me. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generate a Push Certificate
To generate a certificate on a Mac OS X:

1. Log-in to the iPhone Developer Program Portal
2. Choose App IDs from the menu on the right
3. Create an App ID without a wildcard. For example 3L223ZX9Y3.com.armiento.test
4. Click the Configure link next to this App ID and then click on the button to start the wizard to generate a new Development Push SSL Certificate (Apple Documentation: Creating the SSL Certificate and Keys)
5. Download this certificate and double click on aps_developer_identity.cer to import it into your Keychain
6. Launch Keychain Assistant (located in Application, Utilities or search for it with Spotlight) and click on My Certificates on the left
7. Expand Apple Development Push Services and select Apple Development Push Services AND your private key (just under Apple Development Push Services)
8. Right-click and choose "Export 2 elements..." and save as server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 (don't type a password).
9. Open Terminal and change directory to location used to save server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 and convert the PKCS12 certificate bundle into PEM format using this command (press enter when asked for Import Password):

   `openssl pkcs12 -in server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 -out server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem -nodes -clcerts`
10. Now you can use this PEM file as your certificate in ApnsPHP!

Comment: Does these certificate and private key need to be verified. As explained in step 4 of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html . If so can u tell me how to do that.

Comment: NOTE: The openssl command syntax worked on Linux, but not MacOS --- I had to move the pk2 files to a linux box for converting them to pem.

Answer (score 6):

Copied from:
http://www.pressmatrix.de/product-blog/apple-ios-push-notification-setup-guide/

1. Launch the Keychain Access tool and select My Certificates in the left hand panel.
2. Locate the certificate you wish to install and reveal its contents. There should be both a certificate and a private key inside.
3. Select both the certificate and private key, then click File and Export Items. Select Personal Information Exchange (`.p12`) as the output file format.
4. Move the CSR file, `.p12` file and `xxx.cer` files into the same folder and navigate to that location within the terminal window.
5. Convert the `xxx.cer` file into a `cert.pem` file using the following command:

   `openssl x509 -in xxx.cer -inform der -out cert.pem`
6. Convert the private key `xxx.p12` into a `key.pem` file:

   `openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out key.pem -in xxx.p12`

Or refer to:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW5

Comment: What worked for me: After exporting and coverting the bundled 'certificate and private key'.p12 to a .pem file; I opened the bundeled file in a text editor to seperate the 'certificate' and 'private.key' file. Following above steps 4-6 resulted in an empty 'private key' file for me.